# Unable to connect make remote desktop connection

Tags: windows, windows-7, rdp

Here's the setup:

- My home machine, running Windows 7
- First remote machine, also running Windows 7
- Second remote machine, running Windows Server 2012 R2

Both remotes are in local network (and in the same domain) to which I'm connecting from home by VPN.

Here's the problem: I can connect to the second remote with my domain login/pass, everything is peachy. However, when I try to connect to the first machine - connection just closes immediately! With no errors (at least, no obvious error windows or events log entries).

I tried several alternative clients for RDP and most of them behave the same way - connection just closes immediately (but RD Tabs claimed that it was "Unable to authenticate using NLA"). I'm pretty sure that login/password are correct because I can connect to the second machine without reentering them.

Naturally I presumed that something is wrong with first remote. However, if I run Ubuntu in Virtualbox (on the same home machine, using the same VPN connection), I *can* connect to both remotes in Remmina! 
So the first one accepts RDP connections and my user has all the necessary permissions there.

I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Check if the NLA checkbox is selected on Remote Desktop Settings in First Remote Machine, If NLA is disabled can you is there any event registered for system or security

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dead end of life operating system.

Comment: @GregAskew well.. unfortunately many people are stuck with it because of corporate policies or software incompatibility :(

Comment: It is checked; when unchecked I get the error like "Remote host requires NLA"

Comment: It should be unchecked on Both host and remote machines

Comment: Unfortunately I can't disable NLA on remote machine, looks like domain policy prevents me from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. First I tried to connect to the second remote and than, from there, connect to the first :)
Looks like RDP client in Windows Server 2012 is better because it showed me an error:

```
An authentication error has occured. The function requested is not supported.
This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation.
```

So it turned out that first remote (again, due to domain policy) wasn't updating properly for a really long time.
I manually installed `KB4103712` and that fixed my problem!